# Errno 10060 python sending email through gmail

Tags: python, email, gmail

I'm trying to send an email through a `gmail` account using `python 2.7`.  My code is below, any help is appreciated!  I keep getting:

> Errno 10060- connection attempt failed because connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time...

```
import smtplib

FROMADDR = "myemail@gmail.com"
LOGIN    = FROMADDR
PASSWORD = "mypassword"
TOADDRS  = "toEmail@gmail.com"
msg = "Test message"
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 25, timeout=120)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDRS, msg)
server.quit()
print "E-mail succesfully sent"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is timing out because you are connecting on the port [for email routing between servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) instead of the [mail submission agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_submission_agent) port. It worked fine for me when using port 587:

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
>>> server.ehlo()
(250, 'mx.google.com at your service, [99.178.174.213]\nSIZE 35882577\n8BITMIME\nSTARTTLS\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES')
>>> server.starttls()
(220, '2.0.0 Ready to start TLS')
>>> server.ehlo
<bound method SMTP.ehlo of <smtplib.SMTP instance at 0x1e518c0>>
>>> server.login('xxxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx')
(235, '2.7.0 Accepted')
>>> msg = "test message"
>>> server.sendmail('xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com','xxxxxxx@yahoo.com',msg)
{}
>>> server.quit()
(221, '2.0.0 closing connection xxxxxxxxxxxxx.x - gsmtp')
```

Comment: That worked- another problem is a network firewall that I can't get through to connect to another server.  It causes the connection to time out as well.  My code works fine and sends emails at home, but not at work.  Any easy ways around this that you can think of?  Thanks!